# Programmatically add event to Outlook Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, office-365, office-web-apps, sharepoint-calendar

How to programmatically add event to outlook calendar .. I want to programmatically add event to Office outlook calendar.

Comment: Can you please clarify? Are you trying to add an item to a Calendar that resides on a SharePoint site, or one that resides within your Outlook instances on your Office 365 site? They will be different approaches.

Comment: i want to add entry from my outlook instances of office 365

Answer (score 1):

Office 365 exposes the Exchange Web Services in order to allow you to manage things like Calendar items.  In order to use these services, you will need to do the following:

1. Build a client application (in your favorite language) that
   [authenticates with your Office 365 instance using
   OAuth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/jj984319.aspx).
2. Have your client application use the Exchange Web Services to
   [create a Calendar item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633661%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).